# what kind of software do bluetooth speakers use (e.g. BOSE) and can you modify it externally?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a BOSE Soundlink Mini II and I was wondering if there was any backdoor that would allow me to, say, upload custom voice commands (the speaker already has built-in speech production)... but I can't seem to find a lot of documentation that relates to anything beneath the surface i.e. the hardware and software portions of bluetooth speakers. Surely, one should be able to reprogramme such a device? Any input regarding the way bluetooth speakers work 'under the hood' would be appreciated. 
p.s. there is an existing BOSE app which I believe is attempting to address exactly this issue of user customization, but unfortunately, it doesn't support the Soundlink Mini II :(